# Can't get event.target.value in React

Tags: reactjs, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to get a reaction from onInputChange function when I use it with onChange on input, but I didn't get why it's not console.log the value. Any help?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Output from './Components/Output';
import NumberInput from './Components/NumberInput';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      decimal: 0,
      inputString: ''
    }
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }

  render() {
    const { decimal, inputString } = this.state;
    return (
      <fragment>
      <h1>Binary to Decimal convertor</h1>
      <NumberInput InputChange={this.onInputChange} />
      <button>Submit</button>
      <Output string={inputString}/>
      </fragment>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

NumberInput component:

```
import React from 'react';

const NumberInput = ({ inputChange }) => {
    return (
            <fragment>
            <input type='search' onChange={inputChange}></input>
            </fragment>
        )
}

export default NumberInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

## InputChange should be camelcase

change

`<NumberInput InputChange={this.onInputChange} />`

to

`<NumberInput inputChange={this.onInputChange} />`

you may also need to bind

`<NumberInput inputChange={(e) => this.onInputChange(e)} />`

Answer (score 0):

**Need some changes**

Change your `InputChange={this.onInputChange}`
to `inputChange={this.onInputChange}` in **App** component.

because you are accessing `inputChange` in your **NumberInput** component.

And also change your fragment tag as well because you used **fragment** instead of **Fragment** tag.

Either use `<Fragment>`, `<React.Fragment>` or `<>` in **NumberInput**, **App** component like-

```
<Fragment>
  <input type='search' onChange={inputChange}></input>
</Fragment>
```